# es posible desactivar la opción de trabajar con statics en django?

Tags: python, django

Estoy intentando un proyecto personal, digamos como un wix para crear páginas web. Pero sobre Django, pero me surge la duda, ya que la lógica que estoy siguiendo amerita desactivar, trabajar con la carpeta static, ¿es esto posible? Desactivar esa opción en Django y que se trabaje como si estuviera haciendo Font de manera nativa